# How edit mode debug when run app react native

Tags: reactjs, native

I want to public react native app and try to follow as page reactnative dev support. But when i write command

npx react-native run-android -> run app on emulator it only runs debug mode as

[image]

How i can change mode from debug to release mode?

With android/buil.gradle file as

signingConfigs {

```
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
    
    release {
        // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
        // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
```

I am a new react native. So I spent a lot of time to fix but something wrong for it.

Give me any suggestion to fix it.

Thanks so much.!

Answer (score 0):

I finished to publish my react native application. So I want to shared for everyone to do it. Debug mode is default when run by command npx react-native run-android but if i can release ok you can ./gradlew bundleRelease latter.

Follow my steps to fix problem.

1. I make a blank project with command npx create-expo-app
2. Added folder android into project by command expo eject. When create folder android to build released android.
3. Copy code from old folder of the project and paste to new project.
4. Run code by npx expo start
5. Run ./gladlew clean
6. Run npx react-native start and run npx react-native run-android.

Finally follow step public to Google Play Store at [reactnative dev](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)

Good luck to you.!